# H18 Server request interrupted

Tags: heroku

My application is running the free hobby-dev program and free hobby-dev database (https://orandno.herokuapp.com/Files).

If I send a small file in POST body all fine, but if the file is big I recieve error H18 - Server Request Interrupted.

My code in golang on sever side now do almost nothing:

func DBUploadFile(c *gin.Context) {
    c.JSON(200, gin.H{"Uploaded": "OK"})
    return
}

Heroku staff wrote me "There is not a limit on filesize for uploads"...
But why error H18 arise?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku gave more reason why you might end up with that error, which I will advice you read for more clarification [H18 - Server Request Interrupted](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h18-server-request-interrupted), but this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53170225/7905714) should also solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check if it happens the same way in all browsers, or if it's only one browser.

In my case, I got the `Server Request Interrupted` message, only when using **Chrome**. But not when using Firefox, Safari, Edge.

Turned out to be that Chrome sends `zstd` in the `Accept-Encoding`, where the other browsers doesn't send it. I ended up removing the `zstd` on the server.

```
Chrome request header
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd

Firefox request header
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
```

I use django on heroku, and remove `zstd` with this middleware:

```py
class RemoveZstdEncodingMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        ae = request.META.get('HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING', '')
        if 'zstd' in ae:
            new_ae = ', '.join(enc for enc in ae.split(',') if 'zstd' not in enc)
            request.META['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'] = new_ae
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

Idea for alternative solution, change the endpoint from POST to GET.